# DataGrid.SelectedItem not bound to currently selected cell

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, datagrid

Ran into this issue on several occasions.

When finding SelectedItem or selected column on say right click menu or selecting combo box in a cell. The SelectedItem will be null or the previously selected row.

```
private void ComboBox_GotKeyboardFocus(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e) {
// Correct  
m_BeginEditString = ((ComboBox)sender).SelectedValue.ToString(); 

// Wrong. selected item is last selected row, example clicking directly on combobox will not select row, and be null.
m_BeginEditRow = (RowItem)MyDataGrid.SelectedItem; 
}   

<DataGridTemplateColumn>
   <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding myItem, Mode=TwoWay, 
NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource enum}}" 
SelectionChanged="ComboBox_Changed" 
LostKeyboardFocus="ComboBox_LostKeyboardFocus" 
GotKeyboardFocus="ComboBox_GotKeyboardFocus" />
        </DataTemplate>
   </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
 </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: Is this ComboBox in a cell of a DataGrid? In your comments you're talking about clicking, but it looks like you're handling a "KeyboardFocus" event. Could you clarify a bit?

Comment: @glace ComboBox is in cell of DataGrid:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by doing it a completely different way, thanks @Ramesh Muthiah for direction:

```
private void ComboBox_Changed(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e) {
if (((ComboBox)sender).IsLoaded) { // disregard SelectionChangedEvent fired on population from binding
    if (e.RemovedItems.Count != 0) {
        for (Visual visual = (Visual)sender; visual != null; visual = (Visual)VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(visual)) { // Traverse tree to find corred selected item
            if (visual is DataGridRow) {
                DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)visual;
                m_BeginEditRow = new MyRowItem((MyRowItem)row.Item); // Copy constructor, otherwise passed by reference
                break;
            }
        }
        MyEnum newItem = (MyEnum)e.AddedItems[0];
        MyEnum oldItem = (MyEnum)e.RemovedItems[0];
        if (m_BeginEditRow.Combo1 == newItem) {
            m_BeginEditRow.Combo1 = oldItem;
        } else {
            m_BeginEditRow.Combo2 = oldItem;
        }
        DoStuff(m_BeginEditRow, false);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Instead of accessing the selected Item directly, you can access through the parent object and try to access whatever you want. This is alternative approach. I hopes this helps you

```
Combobox objMyButton = null;
        if (sender is Combobox)
        {
            objMyButton = (sender as Combobox );    
        }

        //You can access the parent object which means corresponding DataGridRow and do whatever you want

        for (var vis = sender as Visual; vis != null; vis = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(vis) as Visual)
            if (vis is DataGridRow)
            {
                var row = (DataGridRow)vis;                 
                break;
            }
```

Comment: Don't see why you have the if(sender is ComboBox) also traversing the visual tree works. But spins on these handlers a lot. Such that by the time I want m_BeginEditRow it is the new value, even though the combobox hasn't even closed